# Understanding unknown mesh data structure

Tags: collision-detection, 3d-meshes, mesh

I have a large number of old mesh files in a custom, undocumented binary format. I have managed to parse almost everything but am left with one group of structures, described below, that I don't understand. I hope an experienced graphics programmer can explain what is happening.

Here are the structures concerned:

```
// These types are defined below. We're trying to understand what
// these three arrays are used to achieve.
VertexRef vertexRefs[];
Triangle triangles[];
Unknown unknowns[];

struct VertexRef {
    // Earlier in the file, there are several vertex buffers.
    // The file can contain multiple meshes, either as components
    // of a larger mesh, or as multiple LODs.
    // This value _group_ picks out one of these buffers.
    uint8_t group;
    // Index into the vertex buffer picked out by _group_.
    uint16_t vertexIndex;
};

struct TriangleVertex {
    // Index into the array _vertexRefs_
    uint16_t vertexRef;
    // Index into the array _unknowns_
    uint16_t unknownIndex;
};

struct Triangle {
    TriangleVertex verts[3];
};

struct Unknown {
    // Index into the array _vertexRefs_
    uint16_t vertexRef1;
    // Index into the array _triangles_
    uint16_t triangleIndex1;
    // Another index into the array _vertexRefs_
    uint16_t vertexRef2;
    // triangleIndex2 can be 0xffff, while triangleIndex1 never is
    uint16_t triangleIndex2;
};
```

The array of **VertexRef** is straightforward. It picks vertices, potentially from multiple meshes, to form a composite mesh.

The array of **Triangle** is formed by vertices from the array of **VertexRef**. Each vertex is also associated with an **Unknown**.

I am out of my depth in understanding what **Unknown** is doing. Member **triangleIndex2** sometimes being 0xffff (or invalid, or nonexistent?) might indicate it is a leaf node of a tree? Perhaps the structure comprising the arrays **vertexRefs**, **triangles** and **unknowns** is some kind of collision detection tree?

I'd be very grateful for any hints. Please ask questions if I've failed to be clear enough about something.

**Edit**: In answer to a request in comments, I am attaching a sample file and code to load it. The code should run on any likely system. The file is a mesh of a pair of boots. The file is hosted at uploadfiles.io: https://ufile.io/w66mh

Comment: it could be defined quads. - an index of triangles that are attached together or something. other than that, I can't think of a reason to relate two random triangles on a mesh.

Comment: Would it be useful to you to see a dump of some sample data? For example, I could find a very simple mesh, then include a picture of the mesh and do a text dump of the associated vertexRefs / triangles / unknowns.

Comment: Can you post an example file or how you load the data into these?

Comment: @Bálint, I have attached an example file and code to load it. I hope this helps. Thanks for the interest.

Comment: the 0xffff I have seen where it defines the end of a triangle strip.  That's my previous experience.  That would be inline with API standards I have seen or similar.